# Boto3 S3 error - AccessDenied when calling the PutObjectAcl

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, acl

Trying to generate a publicly-accessible URL for a file that was uploaded into an S3 bucket using the following code:

```
client = boto3.client('s3', config=botocore.client.Config(signature_version=botocore.UNSIGNED))
client.put_object_acl(Bucket="my-bucket", Key=filename, ACL='public-read')
```

throws the exception:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObjectAcl operation: Access Denied
```

My S3 bucket has the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Any tips would be most welcome!
Thanks

Comment: Do you overcome this issue? I'm having the same problem here, even with root account user (permission "*" in every resources).

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that you also need to adjust KMS key access:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/

> Important: If your S3 bucket has default encryption with AWS Key
> Management Service (AWS KMS) enabled, then you must also modify the
> AWS KMS key permissions. For instructions, see My Amazon S3 bucket has
> default encryption using a custom AWS KMS key. How can I allow users
> to download from and upload to the bucket?